# Lucene.NET Stemmer for romanian language

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

I'm looking for a stemmer for the .NET version of Lucene that supports the romanian language. Do you, by any chance, know where I can find one ? Google doesn't seem to be very helpful with this topic.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[lucene-hunspell](http://code.google.com/p/lucene-hunspell/) supports the Romanian language. [Simon Svensson](http://devhost.se/blog/post/2011/04/07/C-port-of-lucene-hunspell.aspx) has ported this to Lucene.net. Seems like it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently any stemmer that specifically supports the Romanian language.